# .Net Core MVC Update database error from model

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-migrations

Apologies if this seems a bit basic, I am trying to do a migration for a website I am building and I keep getting this error when I try to update the database after crating the migration. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Here is the code for the model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Text;

namespace BulkyBook.Models
{
    public class ShoppingCart
    {
        public ShoppingCart()
        {
            Count = 1;
        }
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ApplicationUserId")]
        public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ProductId")]
        public Product Product { get; set; }


        [Range(1, 1000, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a value between 1 and 1000")]
        public int Count { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public double Price { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Order details:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Text;

namespace BulkyBook.Models
{
    public class OrderDetails
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("OrderId")]
        public OrderHeader OrderHeader { get; set; }


        [Required]
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ProductId")]
        public Product Product { get; set; }

        public int Count { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Product:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Text;

namespace BulkyBook.Models
{
    public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string ISBN { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Author { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Range(1, 10000)]
        public double ListPrice { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Range(1, 10000)]
        public double Price { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Range(1, 10000)]
        public double Price50 { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Range(1, 10000)]
        public double Price100 { get; set; }

        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
        public Category Category { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int CoverTypeId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("CoverTypeId")]
        public CoverType CoverType { get; set; }

    }
}
```

[Nuget Package manager console error after Update-Db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8m1b.png)

Comment: can you share your `OrderDetail` and `Product` classes?

Comment: you will have to edit your post ;p

Comment: Haha yes took me a minute to figure that out, thank you, I have updated that now

Answer (score -1):

To solve it
You must define the property 'productid' in orderdetials table ,  as a Nullable

Comment: What would be the best way to do that?

Comment: the best way is : use fluent api in ef core , but i explained you have to use a property as nullable for that problem . this isa a just short way